# How can I apply basic html formatting to a sublime text syntax definition only within

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3, definition

Ok so by the following yaml definition, shouldn't *only* what's in between `{blah}` and `{!blah}` get `text.html.basic` syntax highlighting? And the `{blah}` tags themselves take the highlighting of a comment? Unfortunately it's not happening that way. HTML highlighting is anywhere in the document, and `{blah}` doesn't get comment highlighting.

```
# [PackageDev] target_format: plist, ext: tmLanguage
---
name: Test
scopeName: source.test
fileTypes: [test]
uuid: 3631aac6-ee25-4ec1-ab08-39f156235363

patterns:
  - name: comment.number-sign
  begin: \{blah\}
  end: \{\!blah\}
  patterns:
  - include: text.html.basic
  match: .
...
```

**Sample Code:**

```
{blah}
<input type="text"/>
{!blah}              <----- these are not styled according to comment.number-sign
<input type="text"/> <----- this also has HTML highlighting and I don't want it to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```yaml
# [PackageDev] target_format: plist, ext: tmLanguage
name: Test
scopeName: source.test
fileTypes: [test]
uuid: 3631aac6-ee25-4ec1-ab08-39f156235363

patterns:
- name: html.test
  begin: (\{blah\})
  beginCaptures:
    '1': {name: comment.blah.test}
  end: (\{!blah\})
  endCaptures:
    '1': {name: comment.blah.test}
  patterns:
  - include: text.html.basic
```

The `name` is the base scope for the entire selector. `beginCaptures` and `endCaptures` assign the `comment.blah.test` scope to the `{blah}` tags, while the `include` rule assigns HTML highlighting to whatever is between the `begin` and `end` tags.

Using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (full disclosure: I'm its maintainer), a sample file looks like this:

[image: foo.test]

As you can see, `{blah}` and `{!blah}` are in gray italics, the `comment` scope. Markup outside the `{blah}` tags is not highlighted at all, while that enclosed in the `{blah}` tags is highlighted as HTML.

For more on syntax definitions, check the [tutorial](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) and the [reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html) at the unofficial docs.

Comment: Took me a little while to grasp, but once I got in the flow of it, it all started to make sense.